# Slickgrid using iPad Safari not showing slider

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, slickgrid

I have a slickgrid with 50+ rows which shows a right hand side vertical slider correctly in browsers like Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

On the iPad which uses Safari, the slider is not visible. 
Is there a work around to solve this problem ?

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>SlickGrid example 1: Basic grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../slick.grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="examples.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="50%">
            <div id="myGrid" style="width:600px;height:500px;"></div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <h2>Demonstrates:</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>basic grid with minimal configuration</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <script language="JavaScript" src="../lib/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../lib/jquery.event.drag-2.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="../slick.grid.js"></script>

    <script>

    var grid;

    var columns = [
        {id:"title", name:"Title", field:"title"},
        {id:"duration", name:"Duration", field:"duration"}
    ];

    var options = {
        enableCellNavigation: false,
        enableColumnReorder: false
    };

    $(function() {
  var data1 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            data1[i] = {
                title: "Task " + i,
                duration: "5 days"
            };
        }

        grid = new Slick.Grid($("#myGrid"), data1, columns, options);
    })

    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Slickgrid so can only advise as to what *may* be causing this. It's entirely possible that under the hood it's using a fixed height div, hence the lack of scollbar. I gather some of the fixed height div / scrolling scenarios are fixed in iOS5, but in the meantime you might want to read this post from Matteo Spinelli for some pointers:

[What you can really do with native position:fixed](http://cubiq.org/what-you-can-really-do-with-native-position-fixed)